# How to require parameter to be a generic strictly extending a partial

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to achieve the intuitive result of stating some generic P is a Partial of O.

```
declare function foo<O, P extends Partial<O>>(obj: O, part: P): P
```

However, this allows keys not O for P

```
// no errors
foo({a:2},{a:100, b:2})
```

This does not work either

```
declare function foo<O, P>(obj: O, part: P & Partial<O>): P
```

This version works

```
declare function foo<O, P>(obj: O, part: Partial<O>): unknown

// correct, Typescript complains that `b` is not allowed
foo({a:2},{a:100, b:2})
```

however the return type cannot the generic P.

Does a solution exist to both restrict P to keys in O and have the generic requirement fulfilled?

-- Update

For anyone interested, I've published a gist with some useful partial types that do not allows for excess properties

https://gist.github.com/babakness/a1ca775f81097ffae04098a8cfdadc60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I really understand the use case, nor can I reproduce your results.  The syntax `function foo({a:2},{b:2})` is not how you call a function; if I change that to `foo({a:2},{b:2})` I get [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) complaining about the `b` property.  It is always helpful to make sure you have provided a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to focus answerers' efforts on fixing a problem instead of merely reproducing it.

All that being said, if you really need `P` to have only keys from `O` in it, you can get that behavior (not sure about edge cases) with the following signature:

```
declare function foo<O, P extends { [K in keyof P]: K extends keyof O ? O[K] : never }>(
  obj: O,
  part: P
): P;
```

Now `P` is restricted to a type whose properties must match that of `O` if they exist in `O`, otherwise they must be of type `never` which can't happen with real values.  Test it:

```
const x = { b: 2 }
foo({ a: 2 }, x); // error, types of property 'b' are incompatible
foo({ b: 2 }, x); // okay
foo({ a: 2 }, {}); // okay
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: `function foo({a:2},{b:2})` was a typo, meant  `foo({a:2},{b:2})`

Comment: Interesting to see P extend a computed object made of itself.

Comment: Strange, on my end I don't get errors for first example I've provided. It is "verifiable" on my end; the second example does work as expected I was simply not getting a generic P. Anyway, thank for the help!

Comment: I think verifiability (verifiableness?) is only something you can test using a [separate environment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20function%20foo%3CO%2C%20P%20extends%20Partial%3CO%3E%3E%28obj%3A%20O%2C%20part%3A%20P%29%3A%20P%3B%0Afoo%28%7Ba%3A2%7D%2C%7Bb%3A2%7D%29) otherwise you run the risk of "verifying" something irreproducible.

Comment: Ah, I see, I actually did have an issue, you are right, what I *really* meant is `foo({ a: 2 },{a:100, b: 2})`

Comment: Should you be interested, I created a potentially useful gist for partial types that do not allow excess types https://gist.github.com/babakness/a1ca775f81097ffae04098a8cfdadc60